# Can other member groups register members?

Tags: members, member-management

I have a member group for a client and I want to give them access to manage and register members.

Settings:

**Control Panel Access**
Can access MEMBERS section: YES

**Control Panel Administration**
Can administrate members accounts YES
Can change the group that a member is assigned to (Unlocked groups only) YES
Can administrate member profile templates YES
Can delete members YES

They seem to be able to manage existing users, but get this error when they try and register a member "You do not have the required permissions to add new members to any group." Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, found it...Enable Group Security Lock...first time I had to even mess with that.